# Show submenu on mouseover using AngularJS after half a second

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, mouseevent, ng-animate

I'm trying to create a navigation bar using AngularJS.
I need to show and hide the submenu 'div.farm-links' on mouseover and mouseleave respectively on 'div.menu-links'.

I'm supposed to delay the mouseover on 'menu-links' by 0.5 sec, and similarily on mouseleave, the effect should happen after 0.5 sec. But somehow, this doesn't seem to work.

Could you please help me correct this?
Also, is that possible to achieve using CSS only?

```js
angular.module('topNavApp', ['ngAnimate']).controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.pageData = {  
    "allChildList":[  
      {  
         "pageExist":true,
         "pageTitle":"About Abc",
         "pagePath":"http://www.yahoo.com",
         "openNewTab":true,
         "hideInTabletNav":true,
         "hideInMobileNav":true,
         "secondLevelChildList":[  
            {  
               "pageExist":true,
               "pageTitle":"News",
               "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/news.html",
               "openNewTab":false,
               "thirdLevelChildList":[  

               ],
               "multiple":true,
               "thirdLevelPageExist":true
            },
            {  
               "pageExist":true,
               "pageTitle":"Company",
               "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/company.html",
               "openNewTab":false,
               "thirdLevelChildList":[  
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Strategy",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/company/strategy.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Mission Vision Values",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/company/missionvisionvalues.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Leadership",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/company/leadership.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Org Chart",
                     "pagePath":"http://mysite/pages/OrgChart.aspx",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Corporate Responsibility",
                     "pagePath":"http://myloc2/who/global-impact",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"History",
                     "pagePath":"https://usa.Abc.com/about-Abc/our_business/history-of-Abc.html",
                     "openNewTab":true
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Products",
                     "pagePath":"http://myloc2/who/products",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Investor Info",
                     "pagePath":"http://investor.Abc.com/",
                     "openNewTab":true
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"View All",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/company/view-more.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  }
               ],
               "multiple":true,
               "thirdLevelPageExist":true
            },
            {  
               "pageExist":true,
               "pageTitle":"Community",
               "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/community.html",
               "openNewTab":false,
               "thirdLevelChildList":[  
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Diversity + Inclusion",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/community/diversity-and-inclusion.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Giving Back",
                     "pagePath":"http://myloc2/working/giving-back/Pages/default.aspx",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Ideas Community",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/initiatives/ideas.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Other Communities",
                     "pagePath":"http://myloc2/working/get-involved/Pages/default.aspx",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"View All",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/community/view-all-community.html",
                     "openNewTab":false,
                     "hideInDesktopNav":true
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"myloc Transformation",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/community/transformation.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Calendar",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/about-Abc/community/Calendar.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  }
               ],
               "multiple":true,
               "thirdLevelPageExist":true
            },

         ],
         "columnClass":"0",
         "multiple":true,
         "secondLevelPageExist":true
      },
      {  
         "pageExist":true,
         "pageTitle":"Offices",
         "pagePath":"http://www.yahoo.com",
         "openNewTab":true,
         "hideInDesktopNav":true,
         "hideInTabletNav":true,
         "hideInMobileNav":true,
         "secondLevelChildList":[  
            {  
               "pageExist":true,
               "pageTitle":"Locations",
               "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations.html",
               "openNewTab":false,
               "thirdLevelChildList":[  
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Ashburn",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/ashburn.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Austin",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/austin.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Bangalore",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/bangalore.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Denver",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/denver.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Dubai",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/dubai.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Foster City",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/foster-city.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"San Francisco",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/san-francisco.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Miami",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/miami.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Singapore - Singpost",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/singapore-singpost.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Singapore - Robinson Road",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/locations/singapore-robinson-road.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"View All",
                     "pagePath":"http://myloc.trusted.Abc.com/content/myloc/offices/locations.html",
                     "openNewTab":true
                  }
               ],
               "multiple":true,
               "thirdLevelPageExist":true
            },
            {  
               "pageExist":true,
               "pageTitle":"Quick Links",
               "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/quick-links.html",
               "openNewTab":true,
               "hideInDesktopNav":true,
               "hideInMobileNav":true,
               "thirdLevelChildList":[  
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Copy Centers",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/quick-links/copy-centers.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Floor Maps",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/quick-links/floor-maps.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Food Services",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/quick-links/food-services.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"View All",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/quick-links/view-all.html",
                     "openNewTab":false
                  }
               ],
               "multiple":true,
               "thirdLevelPageExist":true
            },
            {  
               "pageExist":true,
               "pageTitle":"Facilities Help",
               "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/facilities-help.html",
               "openNewTab":false,
               "thirdLevelChildList":[  
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"Submit Request",
                     "pagePath":"http://servicerequest",
                     "openNewTab":true
                  },
                  {  
                     "pageExist":true,
                     "pageTitle":"View All",
                     "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/facilities-help/view-all-facilities-help.html",
                     "openNewTab":false,
                     "hideInDesktopNav":true
                  }
               ],
               "multiple":true,
               "thirdLevelPageExist":true
            },
            {  
               "pageExist":true,
               "pageTitle":"View All",
               "pagePath":"/content/myloc/offices/view-all-offices.html",
               "openNewTab":false,
               "hideInDesktopNav":true,
               "thirdLevelChildList":[  

               ],
               "thirdLevelPageExist":false
            }
         ],
         "columnClass":"3",
         "multiple":true,
         "secondLevelPageExist":true
      },
      {  
         "pageExist":true,
         "pageTitle":"Functions",
         "pagePath":"https://www.google.com",
         "openNewTab":true,
         "hideInDesktopNav":true,
         "hideInTabletNav":true,
         "hideInMobileNav":true,
         "secondLevelChildList":[  

         ],
         "columnClass":"1",
         "multiple":true,
         "secondLevelPageExist":true
      },
      {  
         "pageExist":true,
         "pageTitle":"My HR",
         "pagePath":"/content/myloc/my-hr.html",
         "openNewTab":false,
         "secondLevelChildList":[  

         ],
         "columnClass":"1",
         "multiple":true,
         "secondLevelPageExist":true
      },
      {  
         "pageExist":true,
         "pageTitle":"Tools",
         "pagePath":"/content/myloc/tools.html",
         "openNewTab":true,
         "secondLevelChildList":[  

         ],
         "columnClass":"1",
         "multiple":true,
         "secondLevelPageExist":true
      }
   ]
};
  $scope.showDiv = function(){
 $timeout(function(){
   this.hovering = true;
 }, 500);
  
  };
  $scope.hideDiv = function(){
 $timeout(function(){
   this.hovering = false;
  }, 500);
  };
}]);
```

```css
.hiding-div{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.menu-link{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-link:hover{
 color: #AB09AF;
}

.farm-links{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 height: 400px;
 width: 700px;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 padding: 5px;
 display: flex;
 word-wrap: flex;
 column-count: 4;
}


.groups-links{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 60px;

}

.group-title{
 color: grey;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.group-links{
 list-style: none;
}

.second-link{
 margin-left: -40px;
}

.second-link > a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<nav ng-app="topNavApp" ng-controller="navCtrl" class="nav">
  <div class="nav-center">
 <!--<li ng-repeat="obj in pageData.allChildList" ng-model="parentNav" ng-mouseover="parentNav=true" ng-mouseleave="parentNav=false"> -->
 <div ng-repeat="obj in pageData.allChildList" class="hiding-div" ng-mouseover="showDiv()" ng-mouseleave="hideDiv()" > 
   <div>
  <a ng-href="{{obj.pagePath}}" class="main-link multiple menu-link">{{obj.pageTitle}}</a>
  <!--<span class="main-link mobile" aria-labelledby="{{obj.pageTitle}}" aria-expanded="false">{{obj.pageTitle}}</span>-->

  <!--<span ng-repeat="child in obj.secondLevelVoList" class="childNav" ng-show="parentNav">--> 
  <div class="farm-links" ng-show="hovering">
    <!--<a class="prev-link" aria-labelledby="{{obj.pagetitle}}">{{obj.pageTitle}}</a>-->
    <div ng-repeat="child in obj.secondLevelChildList" class="groups-links">
   <a ng-href="{{child.pagePath}}" class="group-title">{{child.pageTitle}}</a>
   <!--<span class="group-title mobile" aria-expanded="false">{{child.pageTitle}}</span>-->
   <ul ng-repeat="subchild in child.thirdLevelChildList" class="group-links">
     <li class="second-link">
    <a ng-href="{{subchild.pagePath}}">{{subchild.pageTitle}}</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting a script error here. Though the same file, runs perfectly fine in my local setup!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate -> CSS Staggering Animations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define hovering on `$scope`. You can use an array to show the corresponding rows on `ng-repeat`

**JS**:

```
$scope.hovering=[];
$scope.showDiv = function(index) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.hovering[index] = true;
  }, 500);      
};
$scope.hideDiv = function(index) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.hovering[index] = false;
  }, 500);
};
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in pageData.allChildList" class="hiding-div" ng-mouseover="showDiv($index)" ng-mouseleave="hideDiv($index)" > 
      <div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to implement via pure CSS. The issue is in your `this.hovering` variable, in your case it should be `$scope.hovering` instead.

```
$scope.showDiv = function() {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.hovering = true;
  }, 500);      
};
$scope.hideDiv = function() {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.hovering = false;
  }, 500);
};
```

### UPDATE

> *'$scope.hovering' shows all the submenus instead of showing up only the corresponding submenu. How do we fix that?*

Just update the following rows:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in pageData.allChildList" class="hiding-div" ng-mouseover="showDiv(obj)" ng-mouseleave="hideDiv(obj)"> 
...
<div class="farm-links" ng-show="obj.hovering">
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.showDiv = function(obj) {
  $timeout(function() {
    obj.hovering = true;
  }, 500);      
};
$scope.hideDiv = function(obj) {
  $timeout(function() {
    obj.hovering = false;
  }, 500);
};
```

Here we are passing current `obj` from `ng-repeat` to `$scope.showDiv` and `$scope.showDiv` functions, and then we set a new object property like this: `obj.hovering = true;` or `obj.hovering = false;`. And here `ng-show="obj.hovering"` we are showing/hiding this element based on new `obj.hovering` property value.

Comment: '$scope.hovering' shows all the submenus instead of showing up only the corresponding submenu. How do we fix that?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as well! Throws an error 'obj is not defined'.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It works fine! I missed obj at one place!

Comment: @Sunny, nice to hear, that it helps you! If it's really useful, any up votes would be great =)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd also asked another question. Do you mind looking into it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574360/show-a-link-based-on-a-condition-in-angularjs

Comment: @Sunny, i looked through the question, but Brian already gave an answer. Is it OK for you?